# Typescript complex class

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to fill class in typescript. But error 2779.

`error TS2779: The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.`

Class

```
export class SendEmail {
    sender?: ISender
}
interface ISender {
    name: string
    email: string
}
```

Declaration. Here I try fill my class.

```
let mail: SendEmail = new SendEmail();

mail.sender?.email = "test@gmail.com";   //<= error TS2779 here . If I try mail.sender!.email = "test@gmail.com", I have message Cannot set properties of undefined;
mail.sender?.name = "John Doe"
```

It's a simple example. I will have to fill in much larger class with subsub interface.

Thank you for help. I'm beginner in TS.

Comment: What do you want to happen if mail.sender does not exist?

Comment: I thinked mail.sender will be created when we affect value. Like other language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?.` operator is not supported on the left hand side of an assignment (this is a JavaScript limitation)

You need to check for the sender before you assign it's fields:

```
if (mail.sender) {
    mail.sender.email = "test@gmail.com";   
    mail.sender.name = "John Doe"
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GVgDsAmAogLYoCWScA3gFBz1xp77BQD8AXHAJI4Gs0AvjTK4YrAGYoEwHnxZRqdBrhTFgXNDCiiA5svrBSFTdr1CalpMHjGkXeSXKUAvHFzAA7tmZOKACgBKAG5LMgk4fzsAOiZ+KEClBjgYuIVoo2c4NwAicS0AAV0YhAhiHOCGAxTnWOZWaNV1bLgcgCkIAAtcOAARCGAcoSA)

Although you might be better off actually assigning the sender and creating a new object:

```
mail.sender ={
    email: "test@gmail.com",
    name: "John Doe"
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GVgDsAmAogLYoCWScA3gFBz1xp77BQD8AXHAJI4Gs0AvjTK4YrAGYoEwHnxZRqdBrhTFgXNDCiiA5svrBSFTdr1CalpMHjGkXeSXKUAvHFzAA7tmZOKACgBKAG5LOwA6Jn5FF1oGOCNnLgAicS0AAV0IhAhiZIAaA3c1DThkgCkIAAtcOAARCGBkoSA)

Comment: I begin to understand this limitation. Thank you very much.